# Flask-ngrok with google collab, connection error. How Fix?

Tags: python, flask, connection, ngrok, pyngrok

I'm trying to implement a simple graphic interface using Google Colab and Flask Ngrok. However, I'm encountering an issue with the connection. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
   !pip install flask-ngrok
   !pip install pyngrok
   !ngrok authtoken <your_authtoken_here>
```

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

    app = Flask(__name__)
    run_with_ngrok(app)  # Start ngrok when app is run

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World!"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
This error occurs when the following line of code is executed:
`
Ecco una versione della tua domanda che potrebbe essere accettata su Stack Overflow:

Title: Unable to establish connection with Flask Ngrok: ConnectionRefusedError

Body:

Hi,

I'm trying to implement a simple graphic interface using Google Colab and Flask Ngrok. However, I'm encountering an issue with the connection. Here's the relevant part of my code:

python
Copy code
!pip install flask-ngrok
!pip install pyngrok
!ngrok authtoken <your_authtoken_here>
python
Copy code
from flask import Flask
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(**name**)
run_with_ngrok(app)  # Start ngrok when app is run

@app.route("/")
def hello():
return "Hello World!"

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run()

When I run the code, I get the following error:

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
This error occurs when the following line of code is executed:

tunnel_url = requests.get(localhost_url).text

All the errors is:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4040): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/tunnels (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7eb8bc5e9300>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: I think the main problem is you're mixing two unrelated libraries, `flask-ngrok` and `pyngrok`. You only need `pyngrok`. The docs have both Flask and Goolge Colab examples: https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#colab-http-example